# jQuery .load method not firing on IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have 4 divs (class=mydiv), each with an image in, the load method fires on all other browsers I've tested but it does not fire on IE9.0. I don't know if it works in any other IE.

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.mydiv img').load(function(){

        alert("fired");

    });

});
```

Tried using these jQuery versions:

1.4.2
1.5.2
1.6.2
1.5.1rc1

Comment: Check if `prop('complete')` is true and call the callback too.

Comment: What are you trying to load into the img element? Seems to me you need to recheck the documentation of the function; http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @MrThys He is trying to fire an event when an image loads

Comment: I think you are doing soething wrong because i tested this fiddle in IE9 and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/za9AB/

Comment: @MrThys: This is the event: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: the jsfiddle isn't working on my IE 9.0.8112.16421 (Vista SP2). Tried compatibility view and normal view. Works on Firefox and Chrome though.

Comment: It's working on my IE9 WIndows 7!This is strange

Comment: There may be an IE update for me which I will have to try.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE9 problems with jQuery load() event not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137737/ie9-problems-with-jquery-load-event-not-firing)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved using:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 10) {
    window.onload = new function() {
        console.log('LOADED IE');
    }
} else {
    $(window).load(function(){
        console.log('LOADED');
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Shankar Cabus,
you can modify by:

```
if ($.browser.msie) { // For IE only
    $('.mydiv img').onload = new function() {
        alert("fired");
    }
} else {
    $('.mydiv img').load(function(){
        alert("fired");
    })
}
```

Since you want to do something after $('.mydiv img') loaded, but not window loaded.
Hope this helps.