# Vertical waterwheel image carousel scroll with mousewheel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am using the  waterwheel image carousel in vertical mode.
It is working perfectly but I would like to include the a function that allows it to be scroll but the mouse wheel when hover.

Thank you.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.waterwheelCarousel = function (startingOptions) {

    // Adds support for intializing multiple carousels from the same selector group
    if (this.length > 1) {
      this.each(function() {
        $(this).waterwheelCarousel(startingOptions);
      });
      return this; // allow chaining
    }

    var carousel = this;
    var options = {};
    var data = {};

    function initializeCarouselData() {
      data = {
        itemsContainer:         $(carousel),
        totalItems:             $(carousel).find('img').length,
        containerWidth:         $(carousel).width(),
        containerHeight:        $(carousel).height(),
        currentCenterItem:      null,
        previousCenterItem:     null,
        items:                  [],
        calculations:           [],
        carouselRotationsLeft:  0,
        currentlyMoving:        false,
        itemsAnimating:         0,
        currentSpeed:           options.speed,
        intervalTimer:          null,
        currentDirection:       'forward',
        leftItemsCount:         0,
        rightItemsCount:        0,
        performingSetup:        true
      };
      data.itemsContainer.find('img').removeClass(options.activeClassName);
    }

    /**
     * This function will set the autoplay for the carousel to
     * automatically rotate it given the time in the options
     * Can clear the autoplay by passing in true
     */
    function autoPlay(stop) {
      // clear timer
      clearTimeout(data.autoPlayTimer);
      // as long as no stop command, and autoplay isn't zeroed...
      if (!stop && options.autoPlay !== 0) {
        // set timer...
        data.autoPlayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
          // to move the carousl in either direction...
          if (options.autoPlay > 0) {
            moveOnce('forward');
          } else {
            moveOnce('backward');
          }
        }, Math.abs(options.autoPlay));
      }
    }

    /**
     * This function will preload all the images in the carousel before
     * calling the passed in callback function. This is only used so we can
     * properly determine the width and height of the items. This is not needed
     * if a user instead manually specifies that information.
     */
    function preload(callback) {
      if (options.preloadImages === false) {
        callback();
        return;
      }

      var $imageElements = data.itemsContainer.find('img'), loadedImages = 0, totalImages = $imageElements.length;

      $imageElements.each(function () {
        $(this).bind('load', function () {
          // Add to number of images loaded and see if they are all done yet
          loadedImages += 1;
          if (loadedImages === totalImages) {
            // All done, perform callback
            callback();
            return;
          }
        });
        // May need to manually reset the src to get the load event to fire
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137737/ie9-problems-with-jquery-load-event-not-firing
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));

        // If browser has cached the images, it may not call trigger a load. Detect this and do it ourselves
        if (this.complete) {
          $(this).trigger('load');
        }
      });
    }

    /**
     * Makes a record of the original width and height of all the items in the carousel.
     * If we re-intialize the carousel, these values can be used to re-establish their
     * original dimensions.
     */
    function setOriginalItemDimensions() {
      data.itemsContainer.find('img').each(function () {
        if ($(this).data('original_width') == undefined || options.forcedImageWidth > 0) {
          $(this).data('original_width', $(this).width());
        }
        if ($(this).data('original_height') == undefined || options.forcedImageHeight > 0) {
          $(this).data('original_height', $(this).height());
        }
      });
    }

    /**
     * Users can pass in a specific width and height that should be applied to every image.
     * While this option can be used in conjunction with the image preloader, the intended
     * use case is for when the preloader is turned off and the images don't have defined
     * dimensions in CSS. The carousel needs dimensions one way or another to work properly.
     */
    function forceImageDimensionsIfEnabled() {
      if (options.forcedImageWidth && options.forcedImageHeight) {
        data.itemsContainer.find('img').each(function () {
          $(this).width(options.forcedImageWidth);
          $(this).height(options.forcedImageHeight);
        });
      }
    }

    /**
     * For each "visible" item slot (# of flanking items plus the middle),
     * we pre-calculate all of the properties that the item should possess while
     * occupying that slot. This saves us some time during the actual animation.
     */
    function preCalculatePositionProperties() {
      // The 0 index is the center item in the carousel
      var $firstItem = data.itemsContainer.find('img:first');

      data.calculations[0] = {
        distance: 0,
        offset:   0,
        opacity:  1
      }

      // Then, for each number of flanking items (plus one more, see below), we
      // perform the calcations based on our user options
      var horizonOffset = options.horizonOffset;
      var separation = options.separation;
      for (var i = 1; i <= options.flankingItems + 2; i++) {
        if (i > 1) {
          horizonOffset *= options.horizonOffsetMultiplier;
          separation *= options.separationMultiplier;
        }
        data.calculations[i] = {
          distance: data.calculations[i-1].distance + separation,
          offset:   data.calculations[i-1].offset + horizonOffset,
          opacity:  data.calculations[i-1].opacity * options.opacityMultiplier
        }
      }
      // We performed 1 extra set of calculations above so that the items that
      // are moving out of sight (based on # of flanking items) gracefully animate there
      // However, we need them to animate to hidden, so we set the opacity to 0 for
      // that last item
      if (options.edgeFadeEnabled) {
        data.calculations[options.flankingItems+1].opacity = 0;
      } else {
        data.calculations[options.flankingItems+1] = {
          distance: 0,
          offset: 0,
          opacity: 0
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Here we prep the carousel and its items, like setting default CSS
     * attributes. All items start in the middle position by default
     * and will "fan out" from there during the first animation
     */
    function setupCarousel() {
      // Fill in a data array with jQuery objects of all the images
      data.items = data.itemsContainer.find('img');
      for (var i = 0; i < data.totalItems; i++) {
        data.items[i] = $(data.items[i]);
      }

      // May need to set the horizon if it was set to auto
      if (options.horizon === 0) {
        if (options.orientation === 'horizontal') {
          options.horizon = data.containerHeight / 2;
        } else {
          options.horizon = data.containerWidth / 2;
        }
      }

      // Default all the items to the center position
      data.itemsContainer
        .css('position','relative')
        .find('img')
          .each(function () {
            // Figure out where the top and left positions for center should be
            var centerPosLeft, centerPosTop;
            if (options.orientation === 'horizontal') {
              centerPosLeft = (data.containerWidth / 2) - ($(this).data('original_width') / 2);
              centerPosTop = options.horizon - ($(this).data('original_height') / 2);
            } else {
              centerPosLeft = options.horizon - ($(this).data('original_width') / 2);
              centerPosTop = (data.containerHeight / 2) - ($(this).data('original_height') / 2);
            }
            $(this)
              // Apply positioning and layering to the images
              .css({
                'left': centerPosLeft,
                'top': centerPosTop,
                'visibility': 'visible',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'z-index': 0,
                'opacity': 0
              })
              // Give each image a data object so it remembers specific data about
              // it's original form
              .data({
                top:             centerPosTop,
                left:            centerPosLeft,
                oldPosition:     0,
                currentPosition: 0,
                depth:           0,
                opacity:         0
              })
              // The image has been setup... Now we can show it
              .show();
          });
    }

    /**
     * All the items to the left and right of the center item need to be
     * animated to their starting positions. This function will
     * figure out what items go where and will animate them there
     */
    function setupStarterRotation() {
      options.startingItem = (options.startingItem === 0) ? Math.round(data.totalItems / 2) : options.startingItem;

      data.rightItemsCount = Math.ceil((data.totalItems-1) / 2);
      data.leftItemsCount = Math.floor((data.totalItems-1) / 2);

      // We are in effect rotating the carousel, so we need to set that
      data.carouselRotationsLeft = 1;

      // Center item
      moveItem(data.items[options.startingItem-1], 0);
      data.items[options.startingItem-1].css('opacity', 1);

      // All the items to the right of center
      var itemIndex = options.startingItem - 1;
      for (var pos = 1; pos <= data.rightItemsCount; pos++) {
        (itemIndex < data.totalItems - 1) ? itemIndex += 1 : itemIndex = 0;

        data.items[itemIndex].css('opacity', 1);
        moveItem(data.items[itemIndex], pos);
      }

      // All items to left of center
      var itemIndex = options.startingItem - 1;
      for (var pos = -1; pos >= data.leftItemsCount*-1; pos--) {
        (itemIndex > 0) ? itemIndex -= 1 : itemIndex = data.totalItems - 1;

        data.items[itemIndex].css('opacity', 1);
        moveItem(data.items[itemIndex], pos);
      }
    }

    /**
     * Given the item and position, this function will calculate the new data
     * for the item. One the calculations are done, it will store that data in
     * the items data object
     */
    function performCalculations($item, newPosition) {
      var newDistanceFromCenter = Math.abs(newPosition);

      // Distance to the center
      if (newDistanceFromCenter < options.flankingItems + 1) {
        var calculations = data.calculations[newDistanceFromCenter];
      } else {
        var calculations = data.calculations[options.flankingItems + 1];
      }

      var distanceFactor = Math.pow(options.sizeMultiplier, newDistanceFromCenter)
      var newWidth = distanceFactor * $item.data('original_width');
      var newHeight = distanceFactor * $item.data('original_height');
      var widthDifference = Math.abs($item.width() - newWidth);
      var heightDifference = Math.abs($item.height() - newHeight);

      var newOffset = calculations.offset
      var newDistance = calculations.distance;
      if (newPosition < 0) {
        newDistance *= -1;
      }

      if (options.orientation == 'horizontal') {
        var center = data.containerWidth / 2;
        var newLeft = center + newDistance - (newWidth / 2);
        var newTop = options.horizon - newOffset - (newHeight / 2);
      } else {
        var center = data.containerHeight / 2;
        var newLeft = options.horizon - newOffset - (newWidth / 2);
        var newTop = center + newDistance - (newHeight / 2);
      }

      var newOpacity;
      if (newPosition === 0) {
        newOpacity = 1;
      } else {
        newOpacity = calculations.opacity;
      }

      // Depth will be reverse distance from center
      var newDepth = options.flankingItems + 2 - newDistanceFromCenter;

      $item.data('width',newWidth);
      $item.data('height',newHeight);
      $item.data('top',newTop);
      $item.data('left',newLeft);
      $item.data('oldPosition',$item.data('currentPosition'));
      $item.data('depth',newDepth);
      $item.data('opacity',newOpacity);
    }

    function moveItem($item, newPosition) {
      // Only want to physically move the item if it is within the boundaries
      // or in the first position just outside either boundary
      if (Math.abs(newPosition) <= options.flankingItems + 1) {
        performCalculations($item, newPosition);

        data.itemsAnimating++;

        $item
          .css('z-index',$item.data().depth)
          // Animate the items to their new position values
          .animate({
            left:    $item.data().left,
            width:   $item.data().width,
            height:  $item.data().height,
            top:     $item.data().top,
            opacity: $item.data().opacity
          }, data.currentSpeed, options.animationEasing, function () {
            // Animation for the item has completed, call method
            itemAnimationComplete($item, newPosition);
          });

      } else {
        $item.data('currentPosition', newPosition)
        // Move the item to the 'hidden' position if hasn't been moved yet
        // This is for the intitial setup
        if ($item.data('oldPosition') === 0) {
          $item.css({
            'left':    $item.data().left,
            'width':   $item.data().width,
            'height':  $item.data().height,
            'top':     $item.data().top,
            'opacity': $item.data().opacity,
            'z-index': $item.data().depth
          });
        }
      }

    }

    /**
     * This function is called once an item has finished animating to its
     * given position. Several different statements are executed here, such as
     * dealing with the animation queue
     */
    function itemAnimationComplete($item, newPosition) {
      data.itemsAnimating--;

      $item.data('currentPosition', newPosition);

      // Keep track of what items came and left the center position,
      // so we can fire callbacks when all the rotations are completed
      if (newPosition === 0) {
        data.currentCenterItem = $item;
      }

      // all items have finished their rotation, lets clean up
      if (data.itemsAnimating === 0) {
        data.carouselRotationsLeft -= 1;
        data.currentlyMoving = false;

        // If there are still rotations left in the queue, rotate the carousel again
        // we pass in zero because we don't want to add any additional rotations
        if (data.carouselRotationsLeft > 0) {
          rotateCarousel(0);
        // Otherwise there are no more rotations and...
        } else {
          // Reset the speed of the carousel to original
          data.currentSpeed = options.speed;

          data.currentCenterItem.addClass(options.activeClassName);

          if (data.performingSetup === false) {
            options.movedToCenter(data.currentCenterItem);
            options.movedFromCenter(data.previousCenterItem);
          }

          data.performingSetup = false;
          // reset & initate the autoPlay
          autoPlay();
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Function called to rotate the carousel the given number of rotations
     * in the given direciton. Will check to make sure the carousel should
     * be able to move, and then adjust speed and move items
     */
    function rotateCarousel(rotations) {
      // Check to see that a rotation is allowed
      if (data.currentlyMoving === false) {

        // Remove active class from the center item while we rotate
        data.currentCenterItem.removeClass(options.activeClassName);

        data.currentlyMoving = true;
        data.itemsAnimating = 0;
        data.carouselRotationsLeft += rotations;

        if (options.quickerForFurther === true) {
          // Figure out how fast the carousel should rotate
          if (rotations > 1) {
            data.currentSpeed = options.speed / rotations;
          }
          // Assure the speed is above the minimum to avoid weird results
          data.currentSpeed = (data.currentSpeed < 100) ? 100 : data.currentSpeed;
        }

        // Iterate thru each item and move it
        for (var i = 0; i < data.totalItems; i++) {
          var $item = $(data.items[i]);
          var currentPosition = $item.data('currentPosition');

          var newPosition;
          if (data.currentDirection == 'forward') {
            newPosition = currentPosition - 1;
          } else {
            newPosition = currentPosition + 1;
          }
          // We keep both sides as even as possible to allow circular rotation to work.
          // We will "wrap" the item arround to the other side by negating its current position
          var flankingAllowance = (newPosition > 0) ? data.rightItemsCount : data.leftItemsCount;
          if (Math.abs(newPosition) > flankingAllowance) {
            newPosition = currentPosition * -1;
            // If there's an uneven number of "flanking" items, we need to compenstate for that
            // when we have an item switch sides. The right side will always have 1 more in that case
            if (data.totalItems % 2 == 0) {
              newPosition += 1;
            } 
          }

          moveItem($item, newPosition);
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * The event handler when an image within the carousel is clicked
     * This function will rotate the carousel the correct number of rotations
     * to get the clicked item to the center, or will fire the custom event
     * the user passed in if the center item is clicked
     */
    $(this).find('img').bind("click", function () {
      var itemPosition = $(this).data().currentPosition;

      if (options.imageNav == false) {
        return;
      }
      // Don't allow hidden items to be clicked
      if (Math.abs(itemPosition) >= options.flankingItems + 1) {
        return;
      }
      // Do nothing if the carousel is already moving
      if (data.currentlyMoving) {
        return;
      }

      data.previousCenterItem = data.currentCenterItem;

      // Remove autoplay
      autoPlay(true);
      options.autoPlay = 0;

      var rotations = Math.abs(itemPosition);
      if (itemPosition == 0) {
        options.clickedCenter($(this));
      } else {
        // Fire the 'moving' callbacks
        options.movingFromCenter(data.currentCenterItem);
        options.movingToCenter($(this));
        if (itemPosition < 0) {
          data.currentDirection = 'backward';
          rotateCarousel(rotations);
        } else if (itemPosition > 0) {
          data.currentDirection = 'forward';
          rotateCarousel(rotations);
        }
      }
    });


    /**
     * The user may choose to wrap the images is link tags. If they do this, we need to
     * make sure that they aren't active for certain situations
     */
    $(this).find('a').bind("click", function (event) {
      var isCenter = $(this).find('img').data('currentPosition') == 0;
      // should we disable the links?
      if (options.linkHandling === 1 || // turn off all links
          (options.linkHandling === 2 && !isCenter)) // turn off all links except center
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });

    function nextItemFromCenter() {
      var $next = data.currentCenterItem.next();
      if ($next.length <= 0) {
        $next = data.currentCenterItem.parent().children().first();
      }
      return $next;
    }

    function prevItemFromCenter() {
      var $prev = data.currentCenterItem.prev();
      if ($prev.length <= 0) {
        $prev = data.currentCenterItem.parent().children().last();
      }
      return $prev;
    }

    /**
     * Intiate a move of the carousel in either direction. Takes care of firing
     * the 'moving' callbacks
     */
    function moveOnce(direction) {
      if (data.currentlyMoving === false) {
        data.previousCenterItem = data.currentCenterItem;

        options.movingFromCenter(data.currentCenterItem);
        if (direction == 'backward') {
          options.movingToCenter(prevItemFromCenter());
          data.currentDirection = 'backward';
        } else if (direction == 'forward') {
          options.movingToCenter(nextItemFromCenter());
          data.currentDirection = 'forward';
        }
      }

      rotateCarousel(1);
    }

    /**
     * Navigation with arrow keys
     */
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      if (options.keyboardNav) {
        // arrow left or up
        if ((e.which === 37 && options.orientation == 'horizontal') || (e.which === 38 && options.orientation == 'vertical')) {
          autoPlay(true);
          options.autoPlay = 0;
          moveOnce('backward');
        // arrow right or down
        } else if ((e.which === 39 && options.orientation == 'horizontal') || (e.which === 40 && options.orientation == 'vertical')) {
          autoPlay(true);
          options.autoPlay = 0;
          moveOnce('forward');
        }
        // should we override the normal functionality for the arrow keys?
        if (options.keyboardNavOverride && (
            (options.orientation == 'horizontal' && (e.which === 37 || e.which === 39)) ||
            (options.orientation == 'vertical' && (e.which === 38 || e.which === 40))
          )) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      }
    });

    /**
     * Public API methods
     */
    this.reload = function (newOptions) {
      if (typeof newOptions === "object") {
        var combineDefaultWith = newOptions;
      } else {
        var combineDefaultWith = {};
      }
      options = $.extend({}, $.fn.waterwheelCarousel.defaults, newOptions);

      initializeCarouselData();
      data.itemsContainer.find('img').hide();
      forceImageDimensionsIfEnabled();

      preload(function () {
        setOriginalItemDimensions();
        preCalculatePositionProperties();
        setupCarousel();
        setupStarterRotation();
      });
    }

    this.next = function() {
      autoPlay(true);
      options.autoPlay = 0;

      moveOnce('forward');
    }
    this.prev = function () {
      autoPlay(true);
      options.autoPlay = 0;

      moveOnce('backward');
    }

    this.reload(startingOptions);

    return this;
  };

  $.fn.waterwheelCarousel.defaults = {
    // number tweeks to change apperance
    startingItem:               1,   // item to place in the center of the carousel. Set to 0 for auto
    separation:                 75, // distance between items in carousel
    separationMultiplier:       0.7, // multipled by separation distance to increase/decrease distance for each additional item
    horizonOffset:              0,   // offset each item from the "horizon" by this amount (causes arching)
    horizonOffsetMultiplier:    1,   // multipled by horizon offset to increase/decrease offset for each additional item
    sizeMultiplier:             0.6, // determines how drastically the size of each item changes
    opacityMultiplier:          0.6, // determines how drastically the opacity of each item changes
    horizon:                    0,   // how "far in" the horizontal/vertical horizon should be set from the container wall. 0 for auto
    flankingItems:              2,   // the number of items visible on either side of the center                  

    // animation
    speed:                      250,      // speed in milliseconds it will take to rotate from one to the next
    animationEasing:            'linear', // the easing effect to use when animating
    quickerForFurther:          true,     // set to true to make animations faster when clicking an item that is far away from the center
    edgeFadeEnabled:            true,    // when true, items fade off into nothingness when reaching the edge. false to have them move behind the center image

    // misc
    linkHandling:               2,                 // 1 to disable all (used for facebox), 2 to disable all but center (to link images out)
    autoPlay:                   0,                 // indicate the speed in milliseconds to wait before autorotating. 0 to turn off. Can be negative
    orientation:                'vertical',      // indicate if the carousel should be 'horizontal' or 'vertical'
    activeClassName:            'carousel-center', // the name of the class given to the current item in the center
    keyboardNav:                true,             // set to true to move the carousel with the arrow keys
    keyboardNavOverride:        false,              // set to true to override the normal functionality of the arrow keys (prevents scrolling)
    imageNav:                   false,              // clicking a non-center image will rotate that image to the center

    // preloader
    preloadImages:              true,  // disable/enable the image preloader. 
    forcedImageWidth:           0,     // specify width of all images; otherwise the carousel tries to calculate it
    forcedImageHeight:          0,     // specify height of all images; otherwise the carousel tries to calculate it

    // callback functions
    movingToCenter:             $.noop, // fired when an item is about to move to the center position
    movedToCenter:              $.noop, // fired when an item has finished moving to the center
    clickedCenter:              $.noop, // fired when the center item has been clicked
    movingFromCenter:           $.noop, // fired when an item is about to leave the center position
    movedFromCenter:            $.noop  // fired when an item has finished moving from the center
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: 668 lines of code is a little too much. Have a couple minutes to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then, show your attempts to modify it and the relevant code where it stucks.

Comment: I know, sorry for that, but the plugin has alot of optond to change the way it works.   on the last lines you can see them. there is a link here in codepen https://codepen.io/ahung02590/pen/oXKMRp

Comment: But there is no option in the plugin to turn on scroll by mouse wheel

Comment: This plugin seems to be based on `click` to calculate the movement to achieve... It may be hard to tweek. But if you want to try, look at this answer on [how to detect wheel movement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15629039/2159528) and try something! ;)