# IE9, jQuery 1.6.1, and .load()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery .load method not firing on IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870830/jquery-load-method-not-firing-on-ie9)

In IE7 and IE8 this code works, however in IE9, I can't get the .load() function to work on a window handle.

```
var windowHandle = window.open(url, token, "height=150, width=400,alwaysRaised=yes", false);

$(windowHandle).load(function () {
    alert('This is not getting executed in IE9');
});
```

EDIT: Working solution (kind of a hack)

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    if (windowHandle && windowHandle.document && windowHandle.document.readyState && windowHandle.document.readyState == "complete") {
        windowHandle_Load();
    } else {
        $(windowHandle).load(windowHandle_Load);
    } 
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that when your URL is in your browser cache, it finishes loading before you install the `.load()` handler.  To try to detect that condition, you can try this:

```
if (windowHandle.document.readyState == "complete") {
    // already loaded
    alert('This is not getting executed in IE9');
} else {
    // not yet loaded
    $(windowHandle).load(function () {
        alert('This is not getting executed in IE9');
    });
}
```

The property `document.readyState` has been in most browsers for awhile, except it was added to Firefox in 3.6.

Presumably, you would break the code you want to execute out into a common function that you could call in these two places rather than have two copies of it.

Comment: That has the code executing, but I had to wrap your code in a 1000 millisecond setTimeout... or put an alert before it.