# Jquery's load() not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery .load method not firing on IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870830/jquery-load-method-not-firing-on-ie9)

Hi I'm using a simple setInterval and Jquery's Load to get the current date and time :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
       $('#main h1').load('date.php');
         },100);
  });
```

Works fine on chrome but only load's once on ie9 and doesn't update with page refreshes .

Content of date.php :

```
Saturday 21st of January 2012 03:34:31 PM
```

Comment: Are you seriously trying to load this PHP fragment ever 100ms?  Does it work on IE9 if you change the time to something like 5000 to make sure and give it enough time to load before the next one comes a long?  Also, what is the contents of date.php?

Comment: Changing the time made no difference , updated the question with the contents of date.php .

Comment: Do you realize that you could do this entirely with javascript in your page and no involvement of the server at all?  Or, get the initial time once from your server and then update it from then on with javascript?

Comment: @jfriend00 Of course , I was just testing out load and some other things on my new VPS when I stumbled across this , and thought it would be useful to find out what's going on now rather than later . And it was .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
       $('#main h1').load('date.php?' + Math.random());
         },100);
  });
```

Comment: This would have been my response, as IE seems to be aggressive in how it caches AJAX requests.

Comment: @Frank Astin I think, Its a caching issue